# shell script error with modulus operator..which wont take 0 values

Tags: shell, unix

I have an error for the variable "sum_test_sub" when the result of "sum_test" is 0.

```
date_val=16
refresh_count=0

sum_test=$((${date_val#0}%2+refresh_count))
sum_test_sub=$((${sum_test#0}%2))
```

Following is the error:

```
%2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%2")
```

why is the value 0 recognised?? am I doing something wrong?? please help..

Comment: What is purpose of using `${sum_test#0}` in your expression?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to force base 10?  You can do that with `$((10#$sum_test))` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46280785/519360).  Otherwise, see [@paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46280553/519360) about how given `sum_test=0`, `${sum_test#0}` will be an empty string and cause that syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The `${var#0}` construct in `bash` will remove a leading `0` from the `var` variable.

That's fine if you have something like `"07"`, which will give `"7"`. But, where your variable is `"0"`, you will end up with `""`.

Bash can handle `0` as the first argument to modulo just fine, what it *can't* handle is an empty string.

What I'm not sure of is why you're even using the prefix-removal variable expansion since *neither* of your variables start with a `0` anyway.