# strange behavior when fixing integer lengths in bash

Tags: bash, integer, printf, decimal, octal

In my bash script, I set-up the following operations

```
year=0050
echo $(printf %04d $year)
>0040
```

I do not understand why 0040 is returned instead of 0050. I eventually found that to get the system to print 0050 correctly, I will have to do this instead.

```
year=50
echo $(printf %04d $year)
>0050
```

Are there any insights as to why the first case happens?

Comment: If you start your number with `0`, it's interpreted as octal; octal 50 is decimal 40.

Comment: Numeric arguments to `printf` with a leading `0` are interpreted as octal numbers.  Also, why are you calling `echo $(printf ...)`?  `echo` and `printf` both print their output. You can drop the `echo`.

Comment: @larsks Maybe that's because of newlines, but obviously, that's better solved with `%04d\n`.

Comment: @larsks i call echo because I am also combining a month and day into a 8-digit date, so the full line looks like:
    echo $(printf %04d $year)$(printf %02d $month)$(printf %02d $day)

Comment: You should do that with a single `printf` statement instead, like `printf '%04d%02d%02d\n' "$year" "$month" "$day"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you aren't trying to do math, just treat the padded string as the text that it is and use `%s` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because numbers with a leading zero are interpreted as octal by Bash, and octal 50 is decimal 40.

To fix it, you can either strip the zeros with a parameter expansion:

```
$ printf '%04d\n' "${year##+(0)}"
0050
```

I've dropped the `echo $(...)` construct and inserted a newline in the formatting string instead.

Notice that the `+(0)` pattern requires the `extglob` shell option (`shopt -s extglob`).

Alternatively (and more portably), you can convert the number with an arithmetic expansion first:

```
% printf '%04d\n' "$(( 10#$year ))"
0050
```

This uses the `base#n` notation to indicate that *`n`* (in our case: `$year`) is in base 10 and not octal.